# Removing (or rather conditionally attach) const modifier using macros in C

Tags: c, macros, constants

I am dealing with the following issue in C. I use global variables for defining some global parameters in my code. I would like such global variables to be constant, even though they have to be initialized inside a routine that reads their values from an input data file. In a nutshell, I am looking for a good way to "cast away" constness during variable initialization in C (I guess in C++ this would not be an issue thanks to `const_cast`)

I came up with a pattern based on macros to do so, as illustrated below. 
It seems to work fine, but I have the following questions. 
Does anyone see any hidden flaw or potential danger in the procedure below? 
Would anyone discourage the following approach in favor of a simpler one?

My approach:

I have a main header file containing the definition of my global variable (`int N`) like so

```
/* main_header.h */

#ifdef global_params_reader
#define __TYPE__QUAL__
#else
#define __TYPE__QUAL__ const
#endif

__TYPE__QUAL__ int          N;
```

I have a file "get_global_params.c" implementing the initialization of N, which sees N as "`int N`" (as it includes "main_header.h" after defining `global_params_reader`)

```
/* get_global_params.c */

#define global_params_reader
#include get_global_params.h

void get_global_params(char* filename){

    N = ... ; // calling some function that reads the value of N from 
              // the datafile "filename" and returns it

}
```

and the corresponding header file "get_global_params.h"

```
/* get_global_params.h */

#include "main_header.h"

void get_global_params(char* filename);
```

Finally, I have a main.c, which sees N as "`const int N`" (as it includes "main_header.h" without defining `global_params_reader`):

```
/* main.c */

#include "main_header.h"
#include "get_global_params.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    // setting up input data file //
    ...

   // initialize N //
   get_global_params(datafile);

   // do things with N //
   ...
}
```

I hope my explanation was clear enough.
Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: You are overcomplicating it, just create a function to access your global variables which return a const.

Comment: I haven't followed your code completely, but it looks as if your intention is to define the *same variables* as `const` in some places, and non-`const` in others.  I'm pretty sure that will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your implementation violates the one-definition-rule. Don't do it.

Comment: Are you sure you can't just cast away constmness by saying `*(int*)&N` in your initialization routine?

Comment: Casting away `const` from a const-declared variable is **undefined behavior** in either C or C++, regardless of the cast style used. Don't do that. Bugs are known to result from such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just contain the globals in a separate file.

globl.h:

```
struct Globals{
  int N;
  //...
};

extern const struct Globals *const globals;
```

init_globl.h:

```
init_globals(/*Init Params*/);
```

globl.c

```
#include globl.h
#include init_globl.h

static struct Globals _globals;
const struct Globals *const globals = &_globals;

init_globals(/*Init Params*/){
  // Initialize _globals;
  //...
}
```

Now you can initialize the globals at startup by including init_globl.h in whatever file needs access to that functionality, everyone else can directly access the globals just by including globl.h, and using the notation `globals->N`.

Comment: This is probably the best and cleanest way to go about it. Although my question raises a fundamental point which is not quite clear to me, and I can only find controversial and confusing opinions. Suppose in each compilation unit I have a single definition of a global variable (so one-definition-rule satisfied). Can one of these be non-constant while all the other ones are `const`? Is any notion of constness still present during linkage? I have extensively tested this and it seems to work, but many people seem to consider it unsafe and potential source of undefinedness.

Comment: @claudv because of the direction you're going in, this will probably always work. once the object file is generated, the concept of constness is lost. as long as the symbol can be found in some compilation unit it will still work. however, one could probably imagine another environment where this no longer works (i could even imagine this not working in llvm if i try really hard). unfortunately there's no aliasing mechanism like in c++ which would make this whole thing a non issue.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would simply avoid this kind of global variables. Instead, I would define a `struct` with all those program parameters, and define one function that returns a `const` pointer to the one and only instance of this `struct` (singleton pattern). That way, the function that returns the pointer has non-const access to the singleton, while the entire rest of the program does not. This is precisely what you need, it's clean and object oriented, so there is no reason to mess around with macros and casts.

The instance can be declared as a static variable within the function or it can be malloc'ed to a static pointer. It does not really matter, because that is an implementation detail of that function which is never leaked to the outside. Nor does the rest of the code need to be aware of when the parameters are actually read, it just calls the function and it gets the one and only object with all valid parameters.

Answer (score 0):

*"I would like such global variables to be constant, even though they have to be initialized inside a routine that reads their values from an input data file."*

It is not possible to initialize a `const` in c during run-time. In c value either has or has not a `const` qualifier, and it is defined upon declaration. c does not support changing it. The semantics are fixed. But some expert with quoting the standard would be nicer and more ensuring.

I don't think this is possible in c++ either, but I won't bet on it, since c++ can do some magic here and there.